# Can't delete a file unless my user and my user's group own the entire folder

Tags: permissions

I have an `index.php` file in `/var/www/html`:

```
myuser@ubuntu:/var/www/html$ ls -l
-rwxrwxr--  1 www-data     www-data       26 Jun 19 22:50 index.php
```

But I can't delete it unless I use `sudo`. I get permission denied.
But I added myuser to the www-data group (And signed out and signed in):

```
myuser@ubuntu:/var/www/html$ getent group www-data
www-data:x:33:myuser,www-data
```

And the group has all the necessary permissions on the `/var/www/html`:

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data html/
```

and `index.php`:

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data index.php*
```

The only way I can delete this file without using sudo is if I own the entire /var/www with my user and my user's group:

```
sudo chown -R /var/www/html myuser:myuser
```

I also noticed another weird behaviour, as if `myuser` is completely ignored: as you can see in the permissions above, all users have the execute (`r-x`) permissions. And if I remove the execute permission from all users, `myuser`'s access is denied completely. So it's like his permissions in the `www-data` group are ignored

But why? I thought that if I am inside a group, and the group has the appropriate permissions I should be able to delete it as well.

Comment: What is the output of the `id` command? (with the same user who invokes `rm`)

Comment: In Your Previously Deleted Question, I pointed Out that Running:
`sudo chmod -R g+rwX /var/www/html`

Fixes the issue.

**NOTE:** "X" is uppercase.
That way, You don't have to change ownership from `www-data` to `myuser` as You are currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that the user is only added recently to the group and the current shell is started before that, so the group not applied to it:

```
myuser@ubuntu:~$ getent group www-data
www-data:x:33:myuser
myuser@ubuntu:~$ id
uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),118(lpadmin),129(sambashare)
```

If this is the case, you simply reboot the system or just log out and login again. With the `id` command you can check if the problem is fixed (the www-data should appear in the group list)

Comment: Wow I can't believe I only needed to reboot. I did sign out and in but that did not work and since I'm a beginner, I did not use `id` command to check. However after a restart it worked and confirmed with the `id` command. Is there any other way to refresh the group list rather than restarting?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a login (not bash -l but real login) loads the actual groups fine. `ssh localhost `  also does the trick but starting a new terminal in a gui definitely not.